# When BitLocker To Go is enabled automatically, how to write data on external device without encrypting it?

Tags: usb, sd-card, bitlocker

All the machines on our Active Domain have BitLocker To Go installed.

When you plug a USB key or a SD card in the computer, it raises a pop-up that ask you to encrypt the drive/SD card if you want to write data on it.

I would like to be able to skip this for selected drives; typical usages:

- Creating a bootable USB
- Cleaning up the SD card of my camera
- Preparing a USB/SD Card to transfer photos/music to non-Windows OS (e.g. smartTV)

Anyone knows a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/99698/122051).

There are some registry settings that you can set to `0` to turn off the read only access to external drives as enforced by BitLocker To Go.

The settings can be found in the registry as follows:

- `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDenyWriteAccess`
- `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDenyCrossOrg`

I tried in Windows 10 and it works (so far).

Alternatively, you can use the following `.reg` file to update these values automatically:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyWriteAccess"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE]
"RDVDenyCrossOrg"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Note that this is just (locally) disabling the relevant Group Policy. It will be restored the next time your computer refreshes its policies from the domain controller.

Comment: @CBHacking True, but it is for temporary fix anyway.